# Blank/White on certain parts of pages

Tags: custom-background

I am volunteering and helping with the website and for some reason, I cannot get the whites on certain pages to go black:

http://www.remnant13.com/

[image]

How do I make it so that the white parts are all black like the rest of the background?

[image]

Comment: What are you referring to when you say the "white parts"? It will be helpful if you could provide a screenshot to give us a better visual representation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS that you want to run to set your backgroudn color to black:

```
#thepassion_content {
    background: #000;
}
```

You can add that to your child theme's `style.css`, or you can add the following to your child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_winkelwagen' );

function hide_winkelwagen() {
    ?>
    <style itype='text/css'>
    #thepassion_content {
        background: #000;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Either one will give you the same result. If you don't have a child theme, [follow this helpful article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/) on how to easily create on yourself.

Comment: Where would I find the child theme at?

Comment: You'll need to create one if you don't already have one set up. I've updated my answer with a link to an article to get you started.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Thank you so much for your help ^_^

Comment: Sure thing. Be sure to click the checkmark next to this answer to indicate that this question has been solved.